# Azure Resource/Resource Groups using AD Groups

Tags: azure-active-directory

We are trying to find a way to fetch the list of resources to which the AD Groups are mapped to. We have a huge list of AD groups (17k+ AD groups) and we have to update the tags of the resources to which the AD Groups belong to. We have a script to bulk update tags of the resources but we don't have the resource list for these specific resources.

Comment: Hi @ShashwatKumarSingh, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   `As you are confirming that each resource that you have created in Azure has been assigned a tag of the Azure AD group that it is mapped to, then it is quite aptly possible to get the list of resources for which a particular group is mentioned as a tag in it. For that purpose, kindly execute the below powershell command with atleast ‘Contributor’ role Azure assignment to the ID through which this command will be executed`.

To get the **list of Azure resources tagged with the exact value as ‘Reason’ as ‘Repro’**, use the command below: -

```
  (Get-AzResource -Tag @{ “Reason"="Repro"}).Name
```

Output: -

[image: Output-1]

Similarly, if you want the **list of resource groups that have a tag value of 'Reason : Repro' with the exact name and value**, kindly use the below powershell command: -

```
 (Get-AzResourceGroup -Tag @{ "Reason"="Repro" }).ResourceGroupName
```

Output: -

[image: Output-2]

To know more about the commands relating to the above, kindly refer to the below documentation link: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources?tabs=json#list-by-tag***